# Jekyll Serve not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, jekyll-extensions, jekyll-paginator

I have downloaded zip of this github repo - https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes

I have installed `bundler` and I did `bundle install` , it worked perfectly.

Now when I try to run `jekyll serve -w`,

> WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
>         jekyll-watch (~> 1.1) WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs. Please report a bug if this causes problems. Configuration file:
>   /home/kenden/Desktop/minimal-mistakes-master/_config.yml
>
> Dependency
>   Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-paginate or one of
>   its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently
>   configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message
>   from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-paginate' If you run
>   into trouble, you can find helpful resources at
>   http://jekyllrb.com/help/!
>
> jekyll 3.1.3 | Error:  jekyll-paginate

However when I do, `gem list`, it shows me `jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)` along with all the other gems that are installed.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve it using `gem cleanup` followed by `bundle exec jekyll serve`.

Answer (score 7):

If `gem cleanup` and `bundle exec jekyll serve`doesn't work.
Then try `bundle add webrick`. After that you can try `bundle exec jekyll serve`.
And it should work.

Comment: After running all of the above commands, it works now, thanks a lot.

Comment: yep. its working now. thanks a lot.